# From localstorage to POST to PHP variable

Tags: php, ajax, json

I am executing a somewhat complex code from my point of view. It goes like this: First I am getting a list of numbers from localstorage from another page.

```
<script> 
var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('key'));
var localData = data.join(", ");
```

Then I am posting data to PHP code on the same page like this:

```
$.ajax({
type: 'post',
       data: {localData: localData}, 
       dataType: "json",
       success: function(result){
       console.log(result)
       }  
       });
</script>
```

And then I want to put the data into a PHP variable and use it like this:

```
<?php
$user_id = isset($_POST['localData'])?$_POST['localData']:"";
$values = $user_id;
echo $values; ?>
```

The network inspector reveals the data is posted like this: localData 3, 5, 6, 8, 9

But I can't seem to get the data into the PHP variable and echo it. Please help.

Comment: You initial php tag is wrong, change `<php?` to `<?php`, also, Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); `then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: You're also going to have to parse the JSON when it arrives on the PHP side of the fence.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Care to exemplify? :)

Comment: You're posting `{localData: 3, 5, 6, 8, 9}` in your POST-body - you do not have a variable called "localData"

Comment: @Alexander Doesn't this automatically declare the varialbel localData?: `var localData = data.join(", ");`

Comment: @Øyvind yeah, it does, but on the *client side* (Javascript) - you then use more JS to create a JSON Body and post it to your *server side*. On the server side it's just a post body - the server doesn't know anything about Javascript-Variables or JSON - the body could be anything like a a byte[] containing an image or anything else... You can use a server side JSON library to parse the body and retreive the JSON value for localData though...

Answer (score 0):

Your initial php tag is wrong, change `<php?` to `<?php`, also, in order to convert json to an array, you should use [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php), i.e.:

```
<php?
$user_id = isset($_POST['localData'])?$_POST['localData']:"";
$values = json_decode($user_id);
var_dump($values);
```

---

Tip:

Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code.
Remember to comment or remove it in production mode.

Comment: @Pedo Lobito Thank you for your swift response, this seems like it should work but the dump reads "NULL" on the page

Comment: any errors in JavaScript or PHP? if so, please update your answer with it. Is `localData` set ? try `console.log(localData);` to make sure it's set. Debug step by step, until you understand where the code is wrong.

Comment: Before I send it with Ajax post I am able to log it yeah

Comment: do a `print_r($_POST)` in php, what does it yield ?

Comment: So, nothing is being posted.

Comment: But in network inspector it reads the values from localstorage, do you see anything wrong with my $.ajax?

Comment: You may want to read more about the ajax post method http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: From what I understand the variable should post since it is json parsed?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78131/discussion-between-oyvind-hjartnes-and-pedro-lobito).